# MSTest in VS running multiple tests that have similar names

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I have a collection of 30+ tests in the one file and I'm running them using MSTest in Visual Studio as individual tests. I noticed an unusual bug today however. It seems that when I run a test on it's own all other tests that share the same root name as that test also run.

For example if i run TestAddClaim then TestAddClaimWrongID and TestAddClaimWrong EnrollmentAction also run. Similarly if I run TestAddGroupContact then after that has completed TestAddGroupContactWrongGroupID also runs.

Is this a known issue?

I'm going to pre-pend numbers to all of my tests as a way of preventing this from happening. Is there a better solution?

Comment: This has never happened to me. What versions are you using?

Comment: This does not happen to me either.  Even so, you should consider renaming your test methods in this format: MethodTesting_Condition_ExpectedOutcome (e.g. AddClaim_WrongId_ThrowsException, AddClaim_ValidInput_ReturnsTrue).  I can't remember where I first read this, but it is a practice that helps identify the intent of each test very clearly and makes them more maintainable in the long wrong.  It should also resolve your issue.

Comment: How are you running the tests?  If in the IDE, which version?  If from the command line, what command are you using?

Comment: I am running it in VS2008

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design so that you can run multiple tests with one command.  the downside is that you end up unintentionally running multiple tests with one command.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx

I also ran into this, but my tests are on different test lists and have different test traits so I used "/category" to limit the tests run to those containing certain Traits.  You can also use "/testlist" to specify only tests from certain ordered test lists.